VSCode Extension Dev: How to add/configure/run a unit test suite (to add to the integration test suite)?
Background: I am experimenting with creating a vs code extension.
Context: I've started using the project you get from the yeoman scaffolding wizard ( e g npx --package yo --package generator-code -- yo code and yo code as per the getting started tutorial ).
The resulting hello world project ( I think this is the template src ) has a simple test that runs as integration tests in a VS code instance using vscode-test (src/test/extension.test.ts).
(Incidentally, the resulting project is not the same as the vs code extension hello world sample.)
Need: I would like to create some fast running unit tests in this project, to be able to execute those unit tests naturally without running in an VS code instance. (say, unittests.test.ts) So I need a configuration to execute certain unit tests, using just a test runner instead of using vscode-test.
In other words, the end result could be that the project (somehow) includes two test configurations: To run (a) tests that it can run as unit tests of the code (this question) - and not using vscode-test (?), and (b) (integration) tests that start up a separate test instance of vs code using vscode-test (which is what is included in the template to start with).
More context: Since the project uses mocha, I guess I just need to add some launch cfg for those tests. But I am not sure if it is possible or how to use that launch cfg for just some testfiles / tests?
What is there? The project has the basic vscode-test config in .vscode-test.mjs, a config to run extension in .vscode/launch.json and ofc package.json defines the test script as vscode-test.
Question!
Any ideas on:

if and how I can add the configuration to run (1) some tests as "normal" unit tests (not in a test vs code instance) while keeping (2) the ability to run some tests as extension integration tests, starting a vs code test instance using vscode-test?
What configurations do I need to add, to do it as as simple as possible using the template (the yeoman vs code extension template/scaffold result) as a starting point?

What I have tried!
Well, I have tried adding a new launch config (Mocha Tests) and making it active for debug - but that ofc did not have any effect since vscode-test is configured elsewhere, I think. Still vscode-test runs the tests... Is there a way to give VS code a config that runs (some) tests without vscode-test...?

Thanks for reading my question! BR!
